# Вывод value в input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Функция должна выводить в input i-18 value выбранного select

```
function f18() {
    let a = document.querySelector('.s-18');
    let b = document.querySelector('.i-18');

    b.innerHTML = a.value;
}

document.querySelector('.s-18').onchange = f18;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function f18() {
    ...
    b.value = a.value;
}
```